# Filter category product collection and update layered navigation

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm trying to filter product collection for root category to show only new products.

I've managed to filter products by overriding `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer::getProductCollection()` method, but it is not affecting filters in left colum and pagination.

So my question is: how do I update product collection for layered navigation too?